# Springboot cache miss when caching a object

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cache

While using Spring cache in my project, It results in cache miss when I am caching a complex java object ([Tinker Graph](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/3.2.2/full/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/tinkergraph/structure/TinkerGraph.html)) but works fine when caching a String. I am invoking these methods over rest thru a controller layer. Any ideas why this is the behavior ? My code is mostly similar to this [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cache-tutorial).

For eg:

```
SomeService.java
    @Cacheable(NAME_OF_CACHE_1)
    public TinkerGraph getGraph(String graphCode) {
        // do something
        
        // this methods results in cache miss everytime.
    }
    
    @Cacheable(NAME_OF_CACHE_2)
    public String getGraphAsString(String graphCode) {
        // this is working fine and the string result is getting cached.
        return convertToString(getGraph(graphCode));
    }
```

After some debugging I also tried setting up the caches during the startup and could see that the values are cached into the Concurrent Hashmap but still causes the cache miss when returning the Graph instance but works perfectly fine when returning String instance.

```
CacheService.java
@CachePut("NAME_OF_CACHE_1")
public TinkerGraph getGraph(String graphCode) {
    return (TinkerGraph)someService.getGraph(graphCode);
}

@CachePut("NAME_OF_CACHE_2")
public String getGraphAsString(String graphCode) {
    return someService.getGraphAsString(graphCode);
}

@EventListner(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
public void initCache() {
    getGraph("G001");
    getGraphAsString("G001");
}
```

Comment: Your cache key is an `int` in both cases, right?

Comment: @knittl i have updated the question, key is string.

Comment: How are these methods invoked? Also your keys are `int` (the method argument is used as the key).

Comment: @M.Deinum keys are String (methods args). The methods are invoked thru rest call (Controller -> Service)

Comment: Initially your code showed an `int` not a `String`. Also your `@EventListener` won't work as it is an internal method call. The caching is added through AOP and internal method calls don't pass through a proxy. So if the other calls are internal as well (instead of external) the caching won't work. All in all the code you shown is a dumbed down version of your actual code, so please add some actual code.

Comment: @M.Deinum My understanding is that when these methods(in service layer) are invoked from rest controller it should at least cache the data while processing the first rest call and further rest calls should be cache hit.

Comment: @M.Deinum and regarding the @ EventListner - the method which returns String seems to be working fine and it has no cache misses.

Comment: That doesn't make sense as it is an internal method call (judging from what you posted here). So either you aren't telling us everything or this code isn't code you are actually using.